# ListView using two cursoradapters?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I have some code which executes two queries against a database and returns two cursor objects.  Is there any way that I can combine these two cursors so that all the `ListView` gets the data from both?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's [MergeCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) for that (if there's no way to join tables).

Comment: I think there is a way to join tables using SQLiteQueryBuilder setTables (String inTables) methods, I myself is going to try it

Answer (score 9):

FYI - An example of using MergeCursor()

c = Cursor containing Contacts columns from Contacts.CONTENT_URI

```
private Cursor mergeCursorSubset(Cursor c) {

    int userMobile = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,
        workMobile = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE;

    String storedNumber = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            displayName =ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            numberType = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
            contactKey = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY,
            whereClausePre = contactKey+" = '",
            whereClausePost = "AND ("+numberType+" = '"+userMobile+"' OR "+numberType+" = '"+workMobile+"'";


    Uri lookupUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;;

    Cursor [] m = new Cursor[c.getCount()]; 

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        for (int k = 0; k<c.getCount();k++){            
            //Find the mobile numbers
            Cursor u = this.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,
                                                    new String[]{displayName, storedNumber, numberType}
                                                    , whereClausePre+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY))+"') " 
                                                        + whereClausePost, null, null);
            int i = 0;
            if (u.moveToFirst())
                m[i++] = u;

        } //for Each key

    return new MergeCursor(m);

}
```

Comment: can you further explain it?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [cwac-merge](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).

> cwac-merge: Provides the MergeAdapter,
>   a ListAdapter that blends multiple
>   Views or ListAdapters into a single
>   ListAdapter. Use this for section
>   headings, blending multiple sources of
>   data together, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).

Maybe this will help you also [Android - Database Table Join](http://www.thedevsea.com/Solutions/Android/database-table-join-6e601484.html)