# Using cursor.respond(Bundle) & cursor.getextras()

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-viewbinder, mergecursor

I am having 2 cursors from different tables in an SQLite database. I am trying to put the data from the two cursors into one `ListView` but for different formatting for data from each cursor.

What I thought about is using a `MergeCursor` to combine both cursors, but the `ViewBinder` for my `SimpleCursorAdapter` will see them as a single cursor and will not be able to differentiate for formatting (unless I alter my tables, which I do not want to do).

Finally, I found 2 methods called `Cursor.repond(Bundle)` & `Cursor.getExtras()`, but the documentation on the developer console is very short and Googling these methods did not clarify their use.

I tested my idea to use `resond()` in my Database class for the query:

```
    extr.putString("table", the_tab);
    Cursor c_in = db.rawQuery(qry, null);
    c_in.respond(extr);
    return c_in;
```

And use `getExtras()` in the `ViewBinder` to know the table of the query and format the `ListView` item accordingly:

```
Bundle extr=cur.getExtras();
String tab= extr.getString("table");
```

But I am always getting an exception that `tab` is `null`.

My question after this long description is: Am I using the `respond` and `getExtras` methods correctly? And if not, is there a better approach for my problem?

Comment: Why not start with only one Cursor that selects data both tables?

Comment: If you mean Join, I will have the same problem, the ViewBinder will not be able to differentiate the data for formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try building the table name in as a field in the two `SELECT`s.

```
SELECT "A", * from tableA;  SELECT "B", * from tableB;
```

then compute a merged cursor. Alternately,

```
SELECT "A", * from tableA UNION ALL SELECT "B", * from tableB;
```

Now each row of the cursor will have a `"A"` in the first column if it came from `tableA` and a `"B"` if it came from `tableB`. So it's easy to look at this column in your `ViewBinder` to make formatting decisions.

Comment: table_name is not a column in the tables

Comment: I think you misread what I typed.  I've edited to be clearer.  The answer is proposing a different solution than the `extra` data by making a small change to the queries that includes a table name in the first column of each cursor row.

Comment: I really wanted to find a good example of using Cursor.respond and Cursor.getExtras(). However, your solution is the only one that worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the `Bundle` in `getExtras` it seems that `AbstractCursor` which is extended by `AbstractWindowedCursor` which is extended by `SQLiteCursor` defines a `setExtras` method. It's documentation reads

> Sets a android.os.Bundle that will be returned by getExtras(). null will be converted into android.os.Bundle.EMPTY.

`respond` is used for out-of-band communication with the `Cursor` according to the documentation.

So the answer is:

```
((AbstractCursor) cursor).setExtras(bundle);
```

Then you should be able to call

```
cursor.getExtras();
```

at a later time to retrieve that `Bundle`.

**EDIT:**

Upon looking further, it appears that `setExtras` is marked hidden for some reason, so it is public, and is intended to be used as described (and desired). See [ContactsProvider2 example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r2.1/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java#4881)

So, I came up with using a `CursorWrapper`, and overriding the `getExtras` there to provide the `Bundle`. In my case, I create the `Bundle` in the `CursorWrapper`, so I don't need a method for setting it.

```
@Override
public Bundle getExtras() {
    return _meta_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would insist you to have a look at [`MergeCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) and [`AbstractCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html) to get around your problem and get the solution. For example you can check [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235746/listview-using-two-cursoradapters) answer.

Comment: MergeCursor would give me a single cursor that combines my two cursors. I would then use this MergeCursor to fill a single ListView with different formatting for data from the initial two cursors. This is why I am trying to use Cursor.respond and Cursor.getExtras to have like a discriminator for the data to be able to format the row

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative (though [you should not use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code)):

```
Class.forName("android.database.AbstractCursor")
        .getMethod("setExtras", new Class[]{Bundle.class})
        .invoke(c_in, extr);
```